# Hosting custom WCF in IIS using NLB

Tags: wcf, iis, load-balancing, endpoints, nlb

We're in the process of trying to layout a new net topography for our system. We currently host our WCF as a windows service which exposes HTTP, HTTPS, NET TCP, and now AJAX Service endpoints...

Does anyone know if it would be possible to move our WCF into IIS while still having those same exposed end points AND take advantage of IIS Clustering and NLB? Can those exposed end points be part of the NLB? Not sure how it works, I've been doing some research but can't find anything that addresses those concerns.

I'm a little new to WCF and IIS and we're currently in the research phase of this project so any opinions or suggestions would be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis], but you probably meant [tag:load-balancing].

Answer (score 2):

You can move your service hosting from Windows services to IIS as long as you have WAS turned which will be required for tcp bound requests.

You will have to reconfigure your services to support load balancing so take a look at the articles below as a helpful starting point about load balancing.

[Things to Consider When Implementing a Load Balancer with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273122.aspx)

[Load Balancing with the Basic HTTP Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx)

Questions to consider:

Do you use session enabled contract? Does the service behavior use PerSession? Do you have reliable messaging turned on?  Session and reliable session are local to a particular server so failover requires a new session be created. The client has to initiate this by creating a new channel (proxy).

Other helpful articles:

[Unable to connect to Windows Server 2008 NLB Virtual IP Address from hosts in different subnets when NLB is in Multicast Mode](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/01/15/unable-to-connect-to-windows-server-2008-nlb-virtual-ip-address-from-hosts-in-different-subnets-when-nlb-is-in-multicast-mode.aspx)

Comment: do you know if  NLB works with a wcf basicHttpBinding hosted as a windows service?